# How do i find files with a specific extension in a directory that is provided by the user?

Tags: c++

Honestly, i haven't worked with c++ for a couple years now so please bear with me.

I'm not looking for you to write this code for me, just point me in the direction of where i can find the solution (or at least something similar tha ti can work with)

OS: Windows
Using: dirent.h
NOT Using: boost

-PseudoCode

1. START
2. Prompt user for directory
3. **Search directory for all files with .txt extension**
4. If no files then error
5. If files then
6. get files and store the list
7. output file list
8. do other things with files here
9. END

**I know how to accept input from the user but i have no idea how to apply that input (a string which contains the directory path) to be able to navigate and check it for files.**

This is a project for work and it got kind of thrown into my lap all of a sudden.  I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some sample code for iterating through a directory using dirent.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

bool has_suffix(const string& s, const string& suffix)
{
    return (s.size() >= suffix.size()) && equal(suffix.rbegin(), suffix.rend(), s.rbegin());    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Directory name: ";
    string path;
    getline(cin, path);

    DIR *dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    if(!dir)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    dirent *entry;
    while((entry = readdir(dir))!=null) 
    {
        if(has_suffix(entry->d_name, ".txt"))
        {
            cout << entry->d_name << endl;
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```